# Performance Issue Silverlight and WCF Ria Services

Tags: performance, wcf, silverlight, service, ria

Dear developers friends .

In the last month I have faced a problem I can not solve . I know it will be difficult to explain to get some help but I'll try .

I am developing an application in Silverlight , using WCF RIA Services.

The environment of the company where I work has an internal Windows SBS 2003 network that is connected to the Internet through ISA Server .

My application accesses a database that is stored in a SQL Server 2005 full edition .

The database has only 17 tables and no more than 50 records per table .

If I access my Silverlight application in a computer network browser using an internal address , for example , HTTT :/ / myapplication / , the response time is expected, ie , very fast .

If I access my Silverlight application in a computer network with the external address , for example , http://myapplication.domain.com.br browser response time goes very fast .

However , if I access my Silverlight application on a computer that is connected to the Internet via another link that is not my internal network , to load a table with 30 records , the browser takes 30 seconds!

For me when I access the application via internet , there should be no difference if I'm using the same link of the company where I do work the response time should be the same as the route of the data will be the same.

Just as info, I 've installed the same application on another server outside of my company environment in a very powerful server and the problem persists , which leads me to believe that the problem is either in my application or some configuration .

I am researching this problem on the Internet more than 30 days and have found several suggestions but none worked for my case .

If anyone can help, I will be eternally grateful.

Rogerio Picilli .

Comment: I suggest you look at the network traffic your application is generating, there may be some clues there.

Comment: can you please put some domain context method code & related data layer code. If it's taking time to load entities, then it should be something in the code/configuration.

Comment: Usually for different response times depending on whether the page was accessed on an internal network or through the internet I would suspect (and investigate) the amount of data being transferred. You can use something like Fiddler just to determine whether the amount of data you are transferring is reasonable, and optimise how your queries are handled if it isn't reasonable. You say the table has only 30 records, but if a record is a 1MB that is a different situation than bringing back 1000 records of only a few KB.